# Tabbing to next input using querySelector

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jquery-selectors, focus

I am trying to have the input fields tab over to the next field once maxlength is met but I keep getting an error `Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Document': 'name=2' is not a valid selector.`. Ive read over [mozialla's explanation of a querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) and I've tried using the elements `id` to focus() on but that gives the same error. I guess Im not understanding how to properly craft a selector to pass to the querySelector.

My Input fields ill only show 2 i have 3:

```
    <Input
              onChange={dateChange("month")}
              value={date.month}
              id="1"
              maxLength={2}
              type="number"
            />
            <span className="sep">/</span>
            <Input
              onChange={dateChange("day")}
              value={date.day}
              name="2"
              id="2"
              maxLength={2}
              type="number"
            />
```

My onChange:

```
    const dateChange = (field) => (e) => {
    
            const fieldIndex = e.target.name;
            let fieldIntIndex = parseInt(fieldIndex, 10);
            // format to fit
            let value = e.target.value;
          
            if (value.length === e.target.maxLength) {
              if (fieldIntIndex < 3) {
                const nextfield = document.querySelector(
                  `name=${fieldIntIndex + 1}`
                );
                console.log(nextfield);
                if (nextfield !== null) {
                  nextfield.focus();
                }
              }
            }
        
            const d = { ...date, [field]: value };
            setDate(d);
            debounceCallback(handleDateInputChange, d);
          };
```

Im still learning so any advice on this would be great :) thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I think that it is incorrect to set event listeners like this:

```
onChange={dateChange("month")}
```

If you do it that way, you actually execute that function during rendering of the page. The function should be executed when the event occurs. The correct way to do this would be:

```
onChange={dateChange}
```

If you also wanted to add parameters to your function then you should do it like this:

```
onChange={dateChange.bind(this, "month")}
```

Moreover, regarding the query selector, I think the correct syntax would be:

```
const nextfield = document.querySelector(`input[name='${fieldIntIndex + 1}']`);
```

Your name prop is set to an input element, so we use input[name].
Also name has a string value, so we use input[name=''].
Finally we want to set name value parametrically, so we use `input[name='${parameter}']`.

You can find the MDN documentation of bind JavaScript function [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) and the documentation of querySelector [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector).

Edit: Another alternative for navigating among inputs would be the tabindex attribute. You can find more about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/tabindex).

Answer (score 0):

Name is a string So i think you should do it like this(add brackets)
`name='${fieldIntIndex + 1}'`

Comment: That doesnt work it causes an error if im not wrapping the `name=` in a string... Are you saying you think the issue is that the whole item is a string? Like "name=2" ?